# How to? Downgrade Umbraco 7 to version 6 database

Tags: downgrade, umbraco6, umbraco7

We are giving up on Umbraco 7 and want to move back to Umbraco 6. Mostly because of 2 reasons:
1) canvas edit mode is no-where to be found
2) but most importantly, Umbraco Courier does not work with version 7.

We now want to downgrade the v7 database to one of v6. We were hoping that it would be as simple as just pointing v6 to the v7 database (hoping there were no breaking changes).

Does anyone know of a good downgrade strategy for when you do not have a Umbraco 6 version of the db? If it involves some manual work ... that would be ok, as long as we don't have to re-do everything.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is no existing downgrade strategy, you are on your own.  Take your backup and continue from there. If you don't have a backup, well then ...  try to recreate the document types manually.  Create a base service where you can serialize all the [IPublishedContent](http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/Querying/UmbracoHelper/) nodes and create a service on the v6 to pull them in using your best programming skills.

Can't you find another solution for courier? 
Canvas edit is indeed not present.  It can't return in its present state, if you use MVC based rendering.

That being said, I would try to find another solution for courrier in v7 and leave the canvas edit as it is.  Or create your own Javascript based (do I hear surface controller?) canvas edit.  Submit it as a [pull request](https://github.com/umbraco/Umbraco-CMS/pulls) and be the most loved person in the umbraco community.